# Android: Implement Woopra in App

Tags: android

Trying to add **Woopra** in my `Android` App but there is no `SDK` for `Android` provided.
Is there any way to add **Woopra** in `Android App` to `log events`?
Please help me on this if anybody have tried on this topic.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Elie from Woopra. We're publishing an Android SDK this week. You can access it directly on our GitHub account:

https://github.com/Woopra/woopra-android-sdk

We're still doing the final touches but you can always pull the updates.

Elie

Comment: Hi Eile, To add event name if we add space in between then it gives exception. To avoid that we have to use ULR Encoding for each value for event and visitor values. Have to make some changes to get it working for spaces. 
In WoopraTracker.java replace
for (Entry<Object, Object> entry:visitor.getProperties().entrySet()) {urlBuilder.append("&cv_").append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(entry.getValue());}

with

for (Entry<Object, Object> entry:visitor.getProperties().entrySet()) {urlBuilder.append("&cv_").append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(entry.getValue());}

It ll work fine with it